# Why is this condition always true? (pktNum != invPktNum)

Tags: c

When I compile the following code, my compiler complains that the following line is always true. I think I may have a faulty understanding of the `!=` operator...

```
if (pktNum != ~invPktNum) {
    return 1;
}
```

I'm trying to verify that invPktNum is indeed the inverse of pktNum. If not, exit immediately, otherwise proceed as normal.

I've checked and `pktNum` an unsigned char that is 0x01 and `invPktNum` is an unsigned char that is 0xFE at the time of comparison.

Can anybody enlighten me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C, values in most expressions that are of a type narrower than `int` are promoted to a wider type before the calculation takes place.  If `int` is wide enough to hold all the values of the narrower type, then it is promoted to `int`; otherwise it is promoted to `unsigned int`.

In this case, `int` is wide enough to hold all the values of your `unsigned char`, so your values are promoted to `int`.

`pktNum` (and thus, the promoted `pktNum`) can have a value between 0 and 255 inclusive.  This is the value that will be used on the left hand side of the `!=` operator.

`invPktNum` can likewise have a value between 0 and 255 inclusive.  This value will be promoted to `int`, and then bitwise-negated.  The result of this bitwise negation will always be a *negative* number, since the sign bit will be negated.  This is the value that will be used on the right hand side of the `!=` operator.

No negative number can ever be equal to the promoted `pktNum`, so the condition is always true.

To perform the calculation that you actually want to, you need to mask out the lower eight bits after the negation:

```
if (pktNum != (~invPktNum & 0xff)) {
    return 1;
}
```

Or alternatively, you can just negate the bits you're interested in:

```
if (pktNum != (invPktNum ^ 0xff)) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this was it--and I've learned something new. Thank you for your wonderfully detailed answer!

Comment: @FallSe7en: Welcome to the wonderfully confusing world of debugging C-code.  Imagine trying to find that bug without the compiler warning!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at 8-bit values. I bet that pktNum and invPktNum are 32-bit values, so you're comparing 0x000000fe to 0xfffffffe.

Comment: If I'm writing code for a 16-bit microcontroller, would an unsigned char be 16 bits? I had thought an unsigned char was just 8 bits.

Comment: `char` is supposed to be as wide as `CHAR_BIT` from `<stdlib.h>` (I think) defines.

Comment: What type are they? You're not specifying that in your question.

Comment: @FallSe7en, if you're unsure about types' sizes, consider including <stdint.h> and use types like int8_t, uint16_t etc. Then it will be always clear for you how many bits a type occupies.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simple type independent test is:

```
if (0 == (pktNum & pkNum)) {
```

Which is equal to:

```
if (0 == (0xfe & 0x01)) {
```

Quickly tested with http://codepad.org/nziOGYJG seems to work with multiple signed and unsigned long / int types.

Out of interest anybody have any comments?

Comment: That doesn't give the same semantics as the (intended) original - this can only ever be true if and only if one of the inputs is 0.  `if ((pktNum ^ invPktNum) != 0xff)` works, but I don't think it's as clear.

Comment: @caf Thanks for your thoughts. I agree with it not being as clear.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the following:

```
invPktNum = ~pktNum
```

then your comparison is equivalent to:

```
if (pktNum != ~(~pktNum)) {
```

or

```
if (pktNum != pktNum) {
```

which is always false. Unless invPktNum has a different definition in your code which is not shown.

Comment: The compiler complains that it's always *true*.

Comment: Can you add the complete declarations of invPktNum and pktNum to the original question?